# Python timer help needed

Tags: python, datetime, time

This is probably an easy answer but I am very new to python scripting

I have quite a bit of Java programming (especially for android)

So what I want is to start a timer with a predefined time, then do something at the start and another thing when it stops
thanks for any help!

Comment: What about [`Timer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects)?

Comment: Have you done any research before asking this question? See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Comment: @BryanOakley I have actually been busy with this for more than an hour... I just can't get it to work

Comment: That didn't answer my question. If you did research, show what research you did, and what things you've tried. A simple google search of "python timer" returns half a million results. It's hard to believe that none of those results were useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set's a timer for 3 seconds:

```
from time import sleep
print("Starting timer")
sleep(3) #3 seconds
print("Timer ended")
```

Comment: Not exactly the answer I needed, but at least you tried! Thanks!